# .NET 4.0 App running on .NET 4.5.1 crashes in System.Data.dll and hangs after throwing System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-4.5, system.data

When I try to run .NET app targeting .NET 4.0 framework on a computer with only .NET 4.5.1 installed. The application normally runs on cca 50 computers within the same network domain, also on one computer with VS 2012 that has .NET 4.5.1 installed. Only on the one particular machine it crashes.

I am getting "Application not responding" crash within following code:

```
//This line actually opens the connection to SQL Server
var q = (from vlu in data.QVyrobniLinkaUzivateles where (vlu.WinLogin == Program.UserName) orderby vlu.Cislo select vlu); 

MessageBox.Show("A"); //A is displayed
try
{
    MessageBox.Show(q.ToString()); //Here I get the exception 
    LoggedInUser = (q).ToArray(); 
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
 //--------------------------------------------------------------
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);  
 //Application hangs here sometimes displayng the entire exception text, 
 //sometimes displaying only part of it, sometimes displaying nothing
 //When I do not catch this exception then there is sometimes just unhandled exception without any detail in the Event log
 //--------------------------------------------------------------
    MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
}
MessageBox.Show("B");  //B is never displayed
```

Application then hangs on the line MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); It shows application stopped working etc.

The MessageBox (greyed out and not responding) shows sometimes nothing, sometimes following text:
`A connection was successfully established with the server but an error occured during the login process (provider: SSL provider, error: 0 The message received was unexpected or badly formatted)`

Could it be connected with this?

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2915689

[How do I fix an error connecting to SQL Server: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The message received was unexpected or badly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681762/how-do-i-fix-an-error-connecting-to-sql-server-ssl-provider-error-0-the-mes)

What could possibly cause the problem and what steps would you recommend to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: Right, hence the question... *What is the exception?*  Exceptions tend to have useful information regarding the error that occurred, including but not limited to an error message and a stack trace.  All you're telling us is that your application crashed.  We can't know why without more information.  "What could possibly cause the problem" could be just about anything, and the exception is trying to tell you *exactly* what caused it, you're just ignoring that information.  You may need to first modify you're application to *handle exceptions* before you can diagnose this specific one.

Comment: I assure you that a `try`/`catch` construct does, in fact, catch a `SqlException`.  It's much more likely that you're handling the exception incorrectly than that there's a fundamental problem with .NET exception handling.  The code you've shown has no exception handling, so the only reasonable assumption that can be made so far is that you're not handling the exception.  The behavior you describe supports this assumption.

Comment: Define "it hangs on the messagebox."  I can't diagnose code that I can't see.  The original problem still remains... You're not handling the exception and are ignoring the information it contains.

Comment: In your application create an event handler for [AppDomain.UnhandledException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception.aspx) and log all the exceptions. You can get current domain using AppDomain.CurrentDomain. Then you can show us more details on what's actually happening and what are the exception that was thrown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer here worked:

[How do I fix an error connecting to SQL Server: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The message received was unexpected or badly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21681762/how-do-i-fix-an-error-connecting-to-sql-server-ssl-provider-error-0-the-mes)

Installation of .NET 4.5.2 and following updates solved the problem.